# Python: Show a PyMuPDF document with Flask

Tags: python, html, flask, pymupdf

This is a very general question, yet I don't seem to find any answer anywhere.

I have a Python program that manipulates documents using the PyMuPDF library, and then would like to show them through Flask on a `<object>` html tag.
The `data` argument just accepts URL, so I was wondering if it was even possible. Is it possible to show a document on memory without needing to save it onto a file first?

Comment: The reason I’m not using a temporary file is because I already take the document from a SQL database, and I feel like there must be a way of doing this without creating another copy. 
Also, concerning @Jorj McKie, I specify PyMuPdf since I open anyways the document with it, so it may have a function I don’t know about.

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously independent from PyMuPDF. Mentioning it in the title is therefore misleading.
As per your question, I think this is not possible: you must specify a valid URL.
Why not storing the PDF in memory in a temp file?